# Powershell script variable treats comparison operations differently

Tags: powershell, comparison-operators

I have an odd issue where a variable that is part of an if statement is not performing a comparison to a value as expected

The value is in a CSV file. It is a number, not a string so it should work fine. If the value comparison is set to `-eq "0"` it will print out the file entries that have only zero. If I use `-gt` it lists only the values entries not zero. So far so good.

If I use `-le` or `-lt` all file entries will get printed. If I use multiple comparisons such as `-gt "0"` and `-lt "5"` this also does not work - it prints out all values (except those equal to zero of course). I'm at a loss how to get the code to work properly (ignore `Write-host`, that is just so I can see the output).

I'm using `Foreach` because I'll never have more than about 10-20 entries, otherwise I'd go with `Foreach-Object`. Code details are below:

```
$extractFile = "C:\SrvInventory\DBLoginChk.csv"
$passwdexp = 5
$DBdetails = Import-csv $extractfile
Foreach ($DBCreds in $DBdetails) {
    If (($DBCreds.DaysUntilExpiration -gt "0") -and 
        ($DBCreds.DaysUntilExpiration -le $passwdexp)) {
        $Expdt = $($DBCreds.DaysUntilExpiration)
        $DBName = $($DBCreds.LoginName)
        $Emailaddr = $DBName+'@'+'myplace.com'
        Write-host $Expdt
    }
}
```

File contents look like this:

```
"LoginName","DaysUntilExpiration"
"spot","35"
"pup","22"
"cat","21"
"rhino","3"
"camel","1"
"Bull","0"
"warthog","0"
"GViewer","0"
"grandrapids","0"
```

Comment: I know you say that it's a number not a string but are you sure Powershell is seeing it that way when it reads it in?  If you do `Get-Member` on $DBCreds.DaysUntilExpiration what type of object does it return?  Failing that try assigning $DBCreds.DaysUntilExpiration to a variable of its own and see if it likes that (Shouldn't make much of a difference but I have had issues with that in the past).

Comment: Hi Dizzy - when I pipe $DBCreds or $DBCreds.DaysUntilExpiration they both show the field as a Typename: System.String. So as you suggest it appears the field is treated as a string, not a number. Seems odd. I'll try converting it to a number and see if that makes things work properly. Will update here once I'm done. Thanks for your help in putting on the right track

Comment: No problem Paul, this might be of use: [Casting Variables and CSV Data](https://www.fpweb.net/sharepoint-blog/powershell-tips-casting-your-data-types/)

Comment: Thanks Dizzy. I was able to successfully convert the strings to numbers and the whole script now works as expected. I consider the question answered now.

Comment: Awesome.  Good to hear you sorted it :)